# Authenticating calls from Phonegap app to REST server

Tags: rest, cordova, basic-authentication

I'm building an app with Phonegap. It simply reads xml feeds to display latest articles uploaded by a school for parents to read.

There will be an option where each user of the app can decide whether they want to receive Push Notifications or not. I have a simple database table where the device's registration i.d. from Google Cloud Console is stored. When the user clicks "yes", the registration i.d. is generated and stored on the server. If they then click "no", it's deleted. I want to secure these call to the server with basic HTTP authentification.

Any documentation I have seen on basic authentification describes the sending of username and passwords. But with my application, there is no username or password as the users do not need to sign up. What do I send to authenticate the client? Would there be a key hard-coded on the client side and sent with each request? Couln't this be easily exposed by unpacking the .apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have access to server side, you have the control of the whole process. So, in order to handle that, you may think about something like session cookies that a web server creates in case of normal authentication.

I have done something similar and what I've done is to generate a kind of token server side that is stored in the cookies of the device or the localStorage.

So the process flow should be something like this :

- Generate a token and store it on the device (cookies or local storage).
- For each request, send this value in a http header
- From server side, you may identify the user from that token.
  For example : you maintain a table that identifies device/token.

That's it

Answer (score 3):

I object to the premise of the question. I actually see this as less a security issue and more a preferences issue. Understanding the distinction makes the development of your feature much easier.

Simply modify your application to allow the user to configure what he or she wants to see in the settings and then store the preferences wherever you want on the client (like local storage). The server can then push as before, but the app should simply refuse to render those pushes that the user doesn't want to see.

If you want to simply disseminate non-sensitive content to the users who want to see it, this is a preferences issue and/or a publish/subscribe issue. But it is not a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other answers said you can pass a custom useragent string as part of the requests, and validate it matches what you expect. It's not a sure way to 'secure' requests, but along with a (simple) token system and HTTPS this could be enough for your needs.